# Create NodeJS standalone process

Tags: node.js, service

I'm working on something, using NodeJS, that's intended to run as a service that I can connect with.

Let's say I'm working on a Calculator npm module.

I will need to run it within my repo as following:

```
./node_modules/.bin/calculator start
```

And I want to keep it running **forever**, and i can connect it somehow (on port maybe?)

So, I can send/receive messages with the calculator using another node module, let's say 'calculator-connector', for example as following:

```
var calcConnector = require('calculator-connector'),
    calc = calcConnector.connect();

calc.add(1, 2);
```

Any idea how can achieve this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make it like this:

Calculator by itself shouldn't be opinionated, where and when it will run. I'd just create it in the moment I need it:

```
var calculator = require('calculator');
calculator.listen('localhost', 8000); // create the service listening on port 8000
// create client capable of submitting the tasks
calcClient = createCalculatorClient('localhost', 8000) 
calcClient.add(1,2)
```

I believe that such setup is optimal for quick development and debugging.

When you'll need the things to be really separated (say, calculator itself will run on a separate server), you can do simple `node` script which'll run the calculator (basically, it's first 2 lines of the snippet above) and then create simple upstart job (in case of debianish server, or some alternative on other platforms), that'll keep the script alive.

PS:
check out how `express` works, it's beautifully designed:
http://expressjs.com/

read more about upstart:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

To run `calculator` forever, you should use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

> [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.

For connection, you could create a [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or [TCP](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) server.